# Extract list of values from column based upon other column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The following code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "letter" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  "score" = seq(1,6)
)
```

Results in the following dataframe:

```
  letter score
1      a     1
2      b     2
3      c     3
4      d     4
5      e     5
6      f     6
```

I want to get the scores for a sequence of letters, for example the scores of `c("f", "a", "d", "e")`. It should result in `c(6, 1, 4, 5)`.

What's more, I want to get the scores for `c("c", "o", "f", "f", "e", "e")`. Now the `o` is not in the `letter` column so it should return `NA`, resulting in `c(3, NA, 6, 6, 5, 5)`.

What is the best way to achieve this? Can I use `dplyr` for this?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=filter+by+vector+r&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIL820IL820&oq=filter+by+vector+r&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i60j69i65j69i60l2.7182j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to create an index and extract the corresponding 'score'  If there is no match, then by default it gives `NA`

```
df$score[match(v1, df$letter)]
#[1]  3 NA  6  6  5  5

df$score[match(v2, df$letter)]
#[1] 6 1 4 5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("c", "o", "f", "f", "e", "e")
v2 <- c("f", "a", "d", "e")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `dplyr` I would use a join:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "letter" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  "score" = seq(1:6)
)

library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(letter = c("c", "o", "f", "f", "e", "e"))

left_join(df2, df, by = "letter")

  letter score
1      c     3
2      o    NA
3      f     6
4      f     6
5      e     5
6      e     5
```